# Declaring variables inside Spel Expression

Tags: spring, spring-el

I used a lot MVel in the past, and I was using local variables to make expressions cleare.
For example I would hand an expression like this

```
myVar = 32; myVar * 2
```

Then I would use MVel to evaluate this as an Integer and get the result 64.

I cannot find in the Spel documentation how to do this (if it is even possible to do it).

More concretely, how to make the following block work?

```
SpelExpressionParser expressionParser = new SpelExpressionParser();
Expression expression = expressionParser.parseExpression("myVar=32; myVar * 2");
Integer result = expression.getValue(Integer.class);
System.out.println("Result " + result);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no features like "local variable" in SpEL. It is fully based on Java a can evaluate only a single program sentence. What you show with that MVel is essentially two sentences. You can move a complex multi-sentence logic into a Java method and call just that method from the SpEL expression.

More info (and that is exactly a language reference) is in docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#expressions